# How to resolve-call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'Structure_ext' does not have a method 'sessions_end'?

Tags: php-errors

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'Structure_ext' does not have a method 'sessions_end'

Filename: libraries/Extensions.php

Line Number: 265

Comment: Your information is not completed. In which situation and where you get this error? what is version of your EE and structure? Can you update your question with these details and screenshot of error if possible?

Comment: EE version2.5.5 structure 3.3.9.When I upgraded structure to 4.1.12 i got the error

Comment: EE version2.5.5 structure 3.3.9.When I upgraded structure to 4.1.12 i got the error A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: EE::$cache

Filename: helpers/eeharbor_ee2_helper.php

Line Number: 229


Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\intranet-backup\system\expressionengine\third_party\structure\helpers\eeharbor_ee2_helper.php on line 229. Then I removed 4.1.12 folder and stored 3.3.9 back up,then i got the error Message: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback,

Comment: I think downgrade the version must have done something wired. Can you do uninstall the module and install it again.. also, structure save the pages in exp_sites table in base64 format protected by serialize of an array. you should remove all the entries related with structure manually. it is very hard task to do as it can stop your site if you do anything wrong in DB

Comment: Great! Can you answer your question and mark it as accepted so other can get help with similar situation.

Answer (score 0):

**Question**
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'Structure_ext' does not have a method 'sessions_end'

Filename: libraries/Extensions.php

Line Number: 265

EE version2.5.5 
structure 3.3.9.
When I upgraded structure to 4.1.12 i got the error A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice Message: Undefined property: EE::$cache Filename: helpers/eeharbor_ee2_helper.php Line Number: 229 Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\intranet-backup\system\expressionengine\thir‌​d_party\structure\he‌​lpers\eeharbor_ee2_h‌​elper.php on line 229. 
Then I removed 4.1.12 folder and stored 3.3.9 back up,then i got the error Message: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback

Answer

I think downgrade the version must have done something wired. Can you do uninstall the module and install it again.. also, structure save the pages in exp_sites table in base64 format protected by serialize of an array. you should remove all the entries related with structure manually. it is very hard task to do as it can stop your site if you do anything wrong in DB – Mufi 18 hours ago
1
Thanks error solved .I installed it again. – Shiny Muhammed 9 mins ago

Accepted

Comment: Not like that. there is a tick button that you need to click on answer.. (http://prntscr.com/f3x73v). I suggest you to delete your this answer and accept answer given below. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think downgrade the version must have done something wired.

Please try uninstall the module and install it again.

Note: Structure save the pages in exp_sites table in base64 format protected by serialize of an array. you should remove all the entries related with structure manually. it is very hard task to do as it can stop your site if you do anything wrong